# simple tool for compiling Clojure .clj into .class / .jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've found two ways of compiling Clojure *.clj files into *.class files, and while they both work, I have some gripes with both of them.

The [first one](http://dynamic-thinking.blogspot.gr/2009/06/clojure-first-steps-into-compilation.html) uses a REPL and so cannot be automated (or can it?)

The [second one](http://walkwithoutrhythm.net/blog/2012/03/26/how-to-call-clojure-1-dot-3-functions-from-java/) uses **lein**. To be frank I don't see why I should use a dependency management tool for something that should be part of the core tool-chain of the language. But in any case, using **lein** soon [forces you to use a local Maven repository](http://www.pgrs.net/2011/10/30/using-local-jars-with-leiningen/) if your Clojure code needs to access local jars (which is highly likely).

Is there a better way to generate *.class or *.jar files from Clojure code that involves only core Clojure tools and that can be employed in a scripted, non-interactive way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure provides `clojure.core.Compile`, which can be used to compile Clojure code from the command-line.

`java -Dclojure.compile.path=<targetdir> -cp <targetdir>;clojure.jar <list of namespaces>`

For an example of how to use this from ant, look at the `compile-clojure` task in Clojure's own build.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

[clojure.core/compile](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/compile) can be automated via Clojure